# I can't see my siri shortcuts on lock screen using NSUserActivity

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios12, sirishortcuts

I add on the info.plist my strings with the tag NSUserActivityTypes.

I add this piece of code on the viewDidload method of the screen:

NSUserActivity *userActivityTag = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:kVoucher];

```
if(@available(iOS 12.0, *)) {
    [userActivityTag setEligibleForPrediction:YES];
    userActivityTag.suggestedInvocationPhrase = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Let's Voucher this"];
}

[userActivityTag setEligibleForSearch:YES];
[userActivityTag setRequiredUserInfoKeys:nil];
userActivityTag.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Voucher"];
userActivityTag.userInfo = @{
                             @"value":@"key"
                             };

UIImage *logo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage"];
NSData *logoNSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(logo, 1.0f);

CSSearchableItemAttributeSet *attributes = [[CSSearchableItemAttributeSet alloc] initWithItemContentType: (NSString *)kUTTypeItem];
attributes.title = @"title";
attributes.keywords = @[@"implement", @"something", @"lol"];
attributes.contentDescription = @"Subtitle";
attributes.thumbnailData = logoNSData;
attributes.domainIdentifier = @"ownID";

userActivityTag.contentAttributeSet = attributes;
[userActivityTag becomeCurrent];
```

After that I go to that screen and puts a breakpoint in order to probe that the code was executed. 
I switch on both options on Settings -> Developer -> Display recent Shortcuts and Display donations on Lock Screen.

On my AppDelegate I had this:

```
if([userActivity.activityType isEqualToString:kVoucher]) {
    // Restore state for userActivity and userINFO

}
```

So, the question is: Why, I can´t see my shortcut on the lockscreen?

Any help please!

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to see it when you unlock the phone and go to siri suggestion screen?
[image]

Try setting this activity to your current view controller.

```
[self setUserActivity: userActivityTag]
```

Don't know it will help or not but its working for me.